# What's the probability of a number being chosen if it can be chosen twice?

Tags: probability

Given a set of {1,2,3,...,n} numbers and a number can be chosen randomly and there is also the possibility of assigning the same number chosen by two different participants.

My thought process is, since 2 people can choose the same number then there is $2^n$ ways each number could be chosen.

Suppose I want to choose the number k, then the probability someone is assigned that number k is $\dfrac{2^{n-1}}{2^n}$?

Please let me know if I am incorrect. Thank you!

Comment: $2^{n - 1} / 2^{n}$ is basically 1/2

Comment: You're right. I completely overlooked that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If there are $m$ independent and equally probable selections from $n$ numbers, then the probability a particular number *is not* selected is $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^m$

so the probability a number *is* selected is $1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^m$

For $m=2$ this is $\frac2n - \frac1{n^2}$

Comment: Consider choosing a number from $\{0, 1\}$ two times. The possible outcomes are $\{01, 10, 00, 11\}$, which each occur with equal probability assuming we chose the numbers randomly. From the forumula you provided, we have that the probability of choosing the same number twice ($00$ or $11$) is $\frac{2}{2}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$, which as far as I can tell doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Henry (not me) I was talking about the probability a particular number was chosen. In your example the probability of choosing at least one $0$ is $\frac34$, and the probability of choosing at least one $1$ is also $\frac34$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you explain why $\frac{1}{n^2}$ is not the probability that any one number is chosen twice?

Comment: @Henry I would have thought the original question was "What's the probability of a number being chosen?"  rather than "What's the probability of a number being chosen twice?"

Comment: Oh wow, I misunderstood the question, I though the question was about two people choosing the _same_ number, sorry for the confusion!